# Angular NX monorepo build issues

Tags: angular, build, workspace, nrwl

I am having a very hard time getting our Angular 12 monorepo project to build successfully. Here's the scenario:

```
workspace/
├─ apps/
│  ├─ app1/
├─ libs/
│  ├─ libA/
│  ├─ libB/
```

- app1 lazy loads a module in libA and leverages components/enums/interfaces from libB.
- libA leverages components/enums/interfaces from libB.
- I can successfully build the libs outside the app (i.e. `nx build libB` and `nx build libA`). When building the app I get a ton of build errors, some of which are coming from the libs.

I think I'm getting confused on configuring the TS path mapping (@libA and @libB) for the various tsconfigs and lib packaging (ng-packagr) requirements to make VSCode and the compiler happy. Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue through additional refinement of the TS path mappings and fixing import references in the app. So, we're good to go.